# App Store - Help answering "Missing Compliance" (using Expo + Firebase)

Tags: ios, react-native, encryption, expo, app-store-connect

I'm publishing my app to App Store and I have doubts regarding the "Missing Compliance" step.

[image: screenshot apple store UI]

Here's some info about the app:

- I used [Expo (Managed workflow)](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#managed-workflow). That means I don't have direct access to Xcode.
- It's a simple 2D video game, free, with [Expo ADMob](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/admob/). You can pay to remove Ads.
- It requests a camera and library permission (to take a picture if the player wants). No Notifications, or any other extra thing.
- It uses Firebase (Database, Storage, and Analytics) and Sentry. (for HTTPS connections)
- I didn't manually include any "encryption" custom thing (that I'm aware of)
- I'm publishing the App from Portugal, Europe. I plan to publish it worldwide, if possible.

1. **Does your app use encryption?** I didn't code anything related to it... but I assume I should say yes, right?

[image: step 1: encryption]

2. **Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations?**. My app is a simple JS video game, with MobAds. Should I say yes or no?

[image: step 2: exemptions category 5]

3. **Does your app implement any encryption algorithms that are proprietary or not accepted as standards by international standard bodies (IEEE, IETF, ITU, etc.)?** I did say no... is it right?

[image: step 3 - encryptions algorithms]

4. **Does your app implement any standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple’s operating system?** If I say no, it shows an extra message about HTTPS. My app does use HTTPS for Firebase (Database, Storage, and Analytics) and Sentry.

[image: 4. compliance with HTTPS]

5. Finally, if I say yes, it says: **Version 0.1.0 (1) cannot be tested at this time because the build does not have associated export compliance documentation.** Where do I find this documentation and how can I get it? I'm from Portugal, Europe.

[image]

Thank you!

---

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about legal issues and App Store review policies.

Comment: congrats peter!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Question 1**:

> Reply **YES** as ***you use HTTPS encryption for connections***

**Question 2:**

> For what you said about your app the reply is **NO**. In brief you don't use any function inside your app that use a **custom cryptography** or it's **strictly medical app**. *The encryption that you use it's only for data passing from app to server, nothing inside your app is encrypted (app or a part/module of app is not encrypted).*

**Question 3:**

> **No you don't use a custom crypt algorithm**. That is usually used for bank app data inside the app.

**Question 4:**

> Say **NO**. ***The US rules give an exception for apps with only HTTPS calls (that is what you do)***. Read here for a full explanation:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/98071
- https://www.cocoanetics.com/2017/02/itunes-connect-encryption-info/

Comment: Massimo, do you also have an answer for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171884/report-to-us-authorities-using-encryption-to-authenticate-users-for-web-apps

Answer (score 27):

For `expo` users, automatically answer this question by adding this to your `app.json`/`app.config.js`:

```json
{
  "ios": {
    "config": {
      "usesNonExemptEncryption": false / true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this key to `info.plist` file:

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>  
<false/>
```